# Best suitable language for calculation programme/website?

Tags: html, css, mysql, python-3.x

I'm about to enter the world of programming. I know a little bit, but practically nothing, but I'm usually a quick learner when it comes to tech-related stuff.
My brother came up with an idea that I thought I would like to help him with, but I'm not sure what the best way to go about it is.
In order for you to better understand the functionality of the programme/website, here is a little backstory:
My brother spends a lot of time making sourdough for his burger business and optimising his baking all the time.
The way he is keeping track of everything is through an Excel spreadsheet, where amounts of flower, which kinds of flower, cost etc. goes into the spreadsheet.
This is fine if it's only for one type of bread, but he bakes several types of bread.
So, what would the best way to go about building a website for this application be?
I'm thinking that this could be applicable to more than just sourdough, but for simplistic reasons, let just start with that.

The visitor should be able to create a user and that user should be able to store their own recipes, log their changes for future reference and rate the different recipes.

So, on the top of my head, I'm thinking MySql for database, HTML/CSS for styling and Python for functionality?

- Can Python and HTML be integrated?

Let me know what you guys think! All help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use JavaScript for front-end and PHP for back-end?

Comment: @Mystical — They seem more familiar with Python, so why use JavaScript instead of that? (Or PHP now you've edited your comment)

Comment: "Can Python and HTML be integrated?" https://docs.python.org/3.0/howto/webservers.html

Comment: I think I'm gonna go with Brandon Jeffrey's advice and look into Node JS when that is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested into websites javascript and node js is the most popular choice for server development. Python is mostly used for Neural Networking not for server sided development. Do some more research on what is the best to start with. I started with lua for my first language making dedicated servers on roblox,rust, GTA fivem and ect. What ever entertains you the most with programming is where you should start.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was not aware that users were not allowed to ask for suggestions in terms of what languages to use, so the help is much appreciated.